# VBA Excel - Is there a way to delete rows based on criteria in two columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on a macro to clean up a form generated and copied into Excel. I have everything figure out up until the last stage where I need to delete the rows that contain extranious formulas. 
Example:

```
400000  |  Smith, John| 2.4   | 5.66|   =C1+D1
400001  |  Q, Suzy    | 4.6   | 5.47|   =C2+D2
400002  |  Schmoe, Joe| 3.8   | 0.14|   =C3+D3
Blank   |             |       |     |   #VALUE
Blank   |             |       |     |   #VALUE
```

Is there a formula to compare column 'A' to column 'E' and have it delete all rows with no value in 'A', but a value in 'E'?

I've tried a basic loop formula going solely by the empty 'A' column which worked to the point of forever deleting rows below the information I want to keep, and I found a formula dealing with filters on this website (from brettdj) but I did not know how to edit it to properly capture what I needed.

This is what I have from brettdj:

```
Sub QuickKill()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
Set rng1 = Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
Set rng2 = Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
Set rng3 = Range(Cells(rng2.Row, rng1.Column), Cells(1, rng1.Column))
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Rows(1).Insert
With rng3.Offset(-1, 1).Resize(rng3.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=OR(RC1="",RC1<>"")"
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="TRUE"
    .EntireRow.Delete
    On Error Resume Next
    'in case all rows have been deleted
    .EntireColumn.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Some other information:

The first 5 rows of the sheet I want to ignore, they hold column titles and the report name, etc.

The number of rows filled by 40####'s changes, so I can't simply have the macro delete row 4 to whatever.

I don't have extensive knowledge of macro's (obviously) so detailed explanations of how certain portions work would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: well, that formula **FormulaR1C1 = "=OR(RC1="",RC1<>"")"** returns TRUE from either A1="" or A1<>""

Comment: I have added an answer below which uses a SpecialCells trick to find all the rows you want to delete ... BUT, it's dependant on you getting the formula right to test if a row should be deleted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is a way that **doesn't need a loop**

your formula (in Excel spreadsheet) would be something like this:

```
=IF(AND(A:A="",E:E<>""),"DELETE THIS ROW","LEAVE THIS ROW")
```

now, it is possible get that formula to put an error in the rows where I test returns True. The reason we would do this is a feature of Excel called SpecialCells.

In Excel select any empty cell, and in the formula bar type

```
=NA()
```

Next, hit F5 or CTRL+G (*Go to...* on the **Edit** menu) then click the *Special* button to show the SpecialCells dialog.

In that dialog, click the radio next to 'Formulas' and underneath, clear the checkboxes so that only **Errors** is selected. Now click OK

Excel should have selected all the cells in the worksheet with an Error (**#N/A**) in them.

The code below takes advantage of this trick by creating a formula in column H that will put an **#N/A** in all the rows you want to delete, then calling SpecialCells to find the rows, and clear (delete) them...

```
    Sub clearCells()
    '
    Dim sFormula As String
    '
    ' this formula put's an error if the test returns true, 
    ' so we can use SpecialCells function to highlight the
    ' rows to be deleted!
sFormula = "=IF(AND(A:A="""",E:E<>""""),NA(),"""")"
'
' put a formula into column H, to find the rows that ned to be deleted...
Range("H5:H" & Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = sFormula
'
Stop ' next line clears multiple rows, could also delete the entire row!
' now clear the cells returned by SpecialCells ...
Range("H5:H" & Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Offset(0, -7).Clear ' ' EntireRow .Delete shift:=xlup
'
' clean up the formula
Range("H5:H" & Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row).Clear    '
    End Sub
```

copy paste that and step through using F8 ...

then we can help you some more...

Hope that gets you started

BTW, it's also possible **WITH A LOOP** if you really want one :)

Philip

Comment: Thank you Philip! This works perfectly, the only issue I had with it was during testing my formulas in Column 'E' didn't actually have values so they were all #value! which threw off your formula. Once I made sure the formula's had actual answers, everything clicked. It also ran very fast which was fantastic. I appreciate the specifics you gave as well. It was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why using loops was made out to be a bad thing by Philip. Here's a simple macro that goes through every row and deletes rows where `Column A` is empty and `Column E` has some value.

It makes the assumption that your code is on `Sheet 1`. I've commented the code to make it easier for you to follow. If you don't want to consider rows `1-5` for deletion, then set the `For loop` value to `6` as the comment in the code says.

Note that the deletion occurs from the bottom up because when you delete a row the `totalRows` count changes in the loop. To avoid the loop from missing rows I had it simply go in reverse order.

**CODE**

```
Public Sub DeleteWhereEmpty()
    Dim colARowCount As Integer
    Dim colERowCount As Integer
    Dim totalRows As Integer
    Dim currentRow As Integer
    Dim colA As Integer
    Dim colE As Integer
    Dim colACurrentValue As String
    Dim colECurrentValue As String

    colA = 1
    colE = 5
    colARowCount = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, colA).End(xlUp).Row
    colERowCount = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, colE).End(xlUp).Row

    'set total number of rows to look at
    totalRows = colARowCount
    If colARowCount < colERowCount Then
        totalRows = colERowCount 'E has more rows, so use it
    End If

    'to stop deleting at row 5, replace 'To 1' with 'To 6'
    For currentRow = totalRows To 1 Step -1
        colACurrentValue = Cells(currentRow, colA).Value
        colECurrentValue = Cells(currentRow, colE).Text

        'if A is empty and E has data in it, delete the row
        If colACurrentValue = "" Or IsEmpty(colACurrentValue) _
           And Len(colECurrentValue) > 0 Then
            Cells(currentRow, colA).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the loop version, Sam. It ran perfectly despite the formulas not having proper answers to them in column 'E' which was the issue I ran into with testing Philip's, though it took a little bit of time to complete. I'll be keeping both versions in my worksheet just in case. Thank you very much for all your help!